# JavaHelp system help

Tags: java, javahelp

I'm creating a JavaHelp for our project and I'm having some issues.  JavaHelp uses the following files as a convention :

- helpset file: MyHelpSet.hs
- index file:   index.xml
- TOC file (table of contents) : TOC.xml

I've been searching around for tools that help generate these files for you through a wizard, but I don't know what is good or bad.  Can people share their experience?  I know I can manually edit the files but I'm looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had any problems managing these files myself but here are some tools you could look at. (Note I have never used any of them so cannot comment on how good they are).

- [JHelpDev](http://jhelpdev.sourceforge.net/)
- [Help Authoring Tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/industry.html)

Comment: Since writing my question I've managed to handle these files on my own but I just figured there might be some third party tools that help you.  Thanks for the response Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at http://www.pdfhelp.org which offers a free PDF based alternative?